# Calling a member-function from within overloaded operator delete?

Tags: c++, memory-management, operator-overloading

This article on [Binary-compatible C++ Interfaces](http://chadaustin.me/cppinterface.html) contains the code:

```
class Window {
public:
  // ...
  virtual void destroy() = 0;

  void operator delete(void* p) {
    if (p) {
      Window* w = static_cast<Window*>(p);
      w->destroy(); // VERY BAD IDEA
    }
  }
};
```

To me, that seems wrong: `operator delete()` works on **raw memory** with the intended purpose to free it. The object's destructor has already been called, so calling `destroy()` works on a "phantom" object (if it works at all).  Indeed: that's why `operator delete()` takes a `void*` and not a `Window*` (in this case).

So, the design is flawed, right?  (If it is correct, *why* is it correct?)

Comment: Even stranger: In the article's "final implementation", `Window::operator delete` will not actually be called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree (assuming `Window::destroy` is not a static member function):

> 3.8p1: The lifetime of an object of type `T` ends when: if `T` is a class type with a non-trivial destructor, the destructor call starts, or [...]
>
> 3.8p5: [...] After the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released, any pointer that refers to the storage location where the object [...] was located may be used but only in limited ways.  ...  If the object will be or was of a non-POD class type, the program has **undefined behavior** if: the pointer is used to access a non-static data member or call a non-static member function of the object, or [...]

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Just wondering: The language you've posted seems to imply that a class's destructor may not access its own member variables. "The lifetime of an object [...] ends when [...] the destructor call starts", and then, after the lifetime has ended, it is undefined to "access a non-static data member or call a non-static member function of the object." Am I misunderstanding the language as you've posted it? Or has perhaps the intent been distorted by the ellipses? Which standard is this from?

Comment: The quote here is from C++03.  And in that document it does seem overly strict.  C++11 adds: "For an object under construction or destruction, see 12.7.  Otherwise, ...".  There was probably a Standard Defect that resulted in that change.

Comment: Ah, I see that now. Thanks for the citation! :) Yeah, I think it must be just as you say!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that code (if labelled C++) is very wrong.

Operator new and delete as you say handle raw memory, not objects.

That article however deals with specific compilers and specific implementation issues so may be that in that restricted context the code works... moreover MS isn't exactly well renowned for how nicely they care about portable C++ (au contraire, indeed) so **may be** that kind of bad code is (or was in 2002) actually not only working but even a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 0):

That is **really** nasty code, trying to be helpful.

The article says that in COM code should not `delete` the object, but call `obj->destroy()` instead. So to be "helpful" the author makes operator delete do the destroy call. Nasty!

Much better would have been to just declare a private operator delete, so the user cannot delete objects and must instead figure out the correct way.